# How can I find text on screen and get its coordinates using c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, automation, ui-automation, autoit-c#-wrapper

I want to automate a software installed on my machine. I am using AutoIt but on one screen i could not get the control ID or title so that i can access that control and then find text in that. I want to click on that text so i need the coordinates of that text. How i can get the coordinated of that text using c# code or any other third party tool can help me in this?
I have checked on google but i could not get any thing interesting or helpful.
Any thing related this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the "[AutoIt v3 Window Info](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm)"?

Comment: yes i have tried but the problem is AutoIT captures tree view control as a single entity. so it doesn't allow me to select/search some text within treeview control. have you any idea how to find select specific text and finds that text coordinated so that i can click on that particular link.

Comment: Hmm, can you provide an example? It's too much guessing into the blue otherwise. Is there some content in the "Visible Text" field or in the "Hidden Text" field in the Window Info Tool?

Comment: dear i am using software, certain window of that software i need to find some text from tree view control and to find that text coordinates. there are several nodes and several child nodes, and my text in those child nodes in any root node.

Answer (score 0):

As some others said, the question you ask is a bit fuzzy. what kind of software are you looking to automate? What do you want to to automate more precisely? (mouse actions? clicks? something special on the software? ..)

Concerning the mouse clicks for example, there are 2 main ways to automate a process:
Screen coordinates based clicks or window coordinates based clicks.
Below, you can find an example to automate the installation of specific apps 
from the **"web platform installer 5.0"** (which you can download from the Microsoft website @ https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/tools/ -->visual studio 2015)

```
;Gives Admin rights to autoIT
#RequireAdmin
;launches the program in the same directory as the installer
Run(@ScriptDir & '\azure.exe')
;Sets the coordinates as window coordinates with "0" (VS screen coordinates) 
AutoItSetOption('MouseCoordMode',0)
;Waits for the program to open and to display a text like "Microsoft Web Platform Installer"
WinWait("Web Platform Installer 5.0","Microsoft Web Platform Installer")

;wait 1.5 seconds
sleep(1500)
;When the window is visible, le cursor is set as active ont that window (IMPORTANT)

WinActivate("Web Platform Installer 5.0")
;the following commands are mouseclicks on specific boxes of the program to automate specific installs on the installer
;MouseClick('primary', x, y, 1, speed (1 to 10))
; You will find those coordinates in the "AU3info.exe file" after you've installed autoIT ( Au3info allows to find coordinates
; by targeting specific places on a window)
MouseClick('primary', 155, 60, 1, 10)
sleep(1500)
;selects 4 apps to be installed (4 installs), clics INSTALL and waits 1.5 sec
MouseClick('primary', 817, 122, 1, 10)
MouseClick('primary', 821, 163, 1, 10)
MouseClick('primary', 815, 401, 1, 10)
MouseClick('primary', 828, 519, 1, 10)
MouseClick('primary', 692, 587, 1, 10)
sleep(1500)
;Prepaing the install and waiting till a text like "Review the following list" apprears
WinWait("Web Platform Installer 5.0","Review the following list")
WinActivate("Web Platform Installer 5.0")
sleep(1500)
MouseClick('primary', 43, 350, 1, 10)
MouseClick('primary', 603, 433, 1, 10)
;starts the installation and waits till the installation is finished (when "The following"..programm has installed ..blabla
WinWait("Web Platform Installer 5.0","The following")
MouseClick('primary', 612, 434, 1, 2)
;gets rid of some issues stemming from microsoft edge (the send functions allows to send keyboard keys (like ESC, SPACE, ALT, etc..))
sleep(1000)
Send("{ENTER}")
MouseClick('primary', 612, 434, 1, 2)
sleep(1000)
Send("{ENTER}")
;quits all the windows with ALT + F4
WinWait("Web Platform Installer 5.0")
WinActivate("Web Platform Installer 5.0")
Sleep(1000)
Send("{ALT down}{F4 down}{F4 up}{ALT up}")
Sleep(1000)
Send("{ALT down}{F4 down}{F4 up}{ALT up}")
```